Downloadable english translation of the Quran
I feel somehow like being "naked" when it comes to citing/referencing the Quran. I have a very bad translation of the Quran, which I don't even think to look anything up, it is more harm than good (and translated at a time way back when westerners thought all Arabs equal to oil-sheiks or camel drivers, please forgive me, I'm only telling the picture of way back then, don't shoot the messenger). There has been a lot of misunderstanding and misinformation.
I would like to have a reliable and respectable translation into English, preferably with the original Arabic script attached.
Something like the King James Bible is to Christians: not all do agree on every detail of the translation, but most accept it as a good start for a discussion.

"Saheeh International" is a reasonably good English translation in my opinion. If you search you should be able to find it in pdf or even text files.
Mufti Taqi Usmani's translation is also good, see here for a pdf.

Thank you a lot, this looks like a great starting point and gives many translations so that, if in doubt, a different one could be compared.

Take a look at tanzil website, it has several different translations in several different languages ... I personally usually use translations "Sahih International", "Yusuf Ali" and "Shakir", but sometimes beneficial if you consult several translations at the same time, compare them, and even read Ahadeeth describing the evrses, so to understand the meaning better.
